# Disable Telerik Scaffold Visual Studio Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, telerik, telerik-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Can anyone please tell me how can I return back to the default Visual Studio.
Having 'Controller with views, with Entity Framework' as an option is a lot more helpful.

[image: Telerik Scaffold Template]

What I mean with default (MVC5) it is:
[image: Default]

Comment: Id like to also know this!

Answer (score 0):

tools => Extensions and Updates => telerik scaffold delete